# Adicionar variáveis no SLUG WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Estou tentando adicionar variáveis no *slug* do Wordpress, obtive sucesso adicionando da seguinte maneira:

```
function add_var_post( $url, $id ) {
            $url = add_query_arg( 'version', 'teste', $url );
            return $url;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'add_var_post', 10, 2 );
```

Porém eu gostaria de alterar o valor da variável sempre que atualizasse o post da seguinte maneira:

```
function check_values($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){
$var = 'version'; //example
$value = 1544; //example
$result = set_query_var($var, $value); 
}
add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_values', 10, 3 );
```

Porem quando atualizo o post a variável não atualiza o valor para 1544, se mantém o mesmo teste

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, qual o problema? a variável não está sendo atualizada? está dando erro? Isto não ficou muito claro.

Comment: Preciso atualizar o valor da variável que esta estada na url da pagina sempre que der um update no post porem não funciona. O valor mentem sempre o mesmo